# How to animate DataGrid Cell background if a certain data condition is met?

Tags: wpf, animation, datagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid which is populated from a database. There is a cell which gives me a count. I want to add a flashing Background color to that cell if its value is more than 0. Thanks for helping me with my problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a converter that will check to see if a cell contains a number greater than 0:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public class GreaterThanZeroConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
            object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            int cellValue;
            return Int32.TryParse((string)value, out cellValue) && cellValue > 0;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
            object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Include your converter namespace in the xaml. Replace `MyApp` with the namespace of your converter:

```
xmlns:myApp="clr-namespace:MyApp"
```

Your grid will have to look something like this. The objects I am binding to have 2 properties: Col1 and Col2. If the value of Col1 is greater than 0, that cell will flash red.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding List}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <myApp:GreaterThanZeroConverter 
            x:Key="GreaterThanZeroConverter">
        </myApp:GreaterThanZeroConverter>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="FlashStyle">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger 
                    Binding="{Binding Col1, 
                    Converter={StaticResource GreaterThanZeroConverter}}" 
                    Value="True" >
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard 
                                x:Name="Blink" 
                                AutoReverse="True" 
                                RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                    BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                    <EasingColorKeyFrame 
                                        KeyTime="00:00:01" 
                                        Value="Red" />
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn 
            Binding="{Binding Col1}" 
            CellStyle="{StaticResource FlashStyle}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn 
            Binding="{Binding Col2}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

### Edit

If you have to make cells in multiple columns blink based on what they contain, you can change

```
<DataTrigger 
    Binding="{Binding Col1, 
    Converter={StaticResource GreaterThanZeroConverter}}" 
    Value="True" >
  ...
```

To

```
<DataTrigger 
    Binding="{Binding 
        Content.Text,
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
        Converter={StaticResource GreaterThanZeroConverter}}" 
    Value="True" >
```

And set the CellStyle for each of the columns that you want to blink to our FlashStyle:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn 
        Binding="{Binding Col1}" 
        CellStyle="{StaticResource FlashStyle}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn 
        Binding="{Binding Col2}"
        CellStyle="{StaticResource FlashStyle}"></DataGridTextColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Note that this will probably only work with DataGridTextColumns. If you are using DataGridTemplateColumns it will be a bit more tricky.

Comment: What If I want to use the same for more than 1 column? It is giving me a run time error if I apply it to more than 1 column. "Cannot duplicate Blink"

Comment: That depends. Do you want each cell to blink if it contains a value > 0? Or will you always be looking for the value in one column and just having cells in other columns blink?

Comment: I want each cell to blink if it contains value > 0. Can that be done?

Comment: I will be looking for values in 4 different columns and want them to blink if any of the value > 0.

Comment: I am using only DataGrid Columns. I will give it a try and tell you how it works for my scenario.

Comment: And What If I want different colors in different columns?

Comment: Then just copy the style, give it a new Key, change the Value in the EasingColorKeyFrame to the other color, and set that as the column CellStyle.

Comment: Thanks a Lot kevev22. It is working now. It is really helpful.